# 1970s book about global warming

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a book sometime around 1979/1980 with the theme of global warming.  I can recall that people were keeping the information quiet because they feared people would go to war to stop other nations from generating too much heat/carbon dioxide and that the eventual solution was to create infrared satellites to beam heat out into space.  Not the most scientifically sound story but prescient in the current climate.  Can anyone point me in the direction of the title or author?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds a lot like the 1978 novel [Heat](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/80122.Heat) by Arthur Herzog which was republished in 2003.

A brief excerpt is below which matches the "secret" nature of the group working to try and reverse the process.

> Lawrence Pick, engineer, gathers startling evidence that the world’s weather may be rapidly changing, as a prelude to a fundamental alteration in global climate. **In a secret underground laboratory,** he and a team of equally skilled scientists learn that the level of carbon dioxide in the atmosphere, largely due to the overuse of energy, will ascend to the point where no living thing can survive.
>
> Pick’s predictions become a reality as freakish weather conditions prevail: extraordinary tornados and hurricanes, droughts, violent hailstorms, and windstorms and savage waterspouts. “Condition Green” is no longer a theory as destruction runs rampant, but still neither the U.S. Government nor the people will listen. Too late, the result of man’s indifference is everywhere…with only one hope for survival.

What also matches as I recall in the end:

> Pick and the team of engineers develop a way to "shield" the Earth by redirecting he solar radiation away from the planet, reducing what is trapped by the greenhouse effect.

As a "spoiler" which you might remember:

> after the redirection starts and before it actually works, Pick almost commits suicide thinking it has failed and that humanity is doomed.

Comment: That sounds exactly like it!  Thank you.

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Hothouse Earth by Harold Wilcox - 1975

[https://www.amazon.com/Hothouse-earth-Howard-Wilcox/dp/027552910X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/027552910X)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain how this matches the details of the question?

Comment: Also note that the OP marked [beichst's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/106522/122024) of _Heat_ (1978) by Arthur Herzog as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), as denoted by the green tick to the left of that answer, and left [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106058/1970s-book-about-global-warming#comment250512_106522) beneath the answer indicating that they believed that was the book they were looking for.

Comment: I thought this might be the book.  Didn't know anything about the green tick.

Answer (score -1):

Try a more recent book called, "The Storms of our Grandchildren". Maybe "The Storms of our Children". It is one of those.

Comment: Welcome to sff.se!  May I suggest you take the [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).  Here on sff.se reading suggestions are off topic,  and we avoid giving answers that don't answer the question.

Comment: If you think one of those two books is an answer, can you provide some explanation as to why? it will help the OP determine if you've found the right book...